# How to prevent duplicate code generation when placing winforms event handlers in other partial files

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, code-generation

In a winforms application I have a MyForm.cs that starts to get quite large.
To solve this I have created a new file(MyForm.LeftPanel.cs) using partial class of the MyForm class with a subset of the GUI functionality.

However once in a while, not always, when I go into the designer all event handlers that I have moved to MyForm.LeftPanel.cs gets regenerated in MyForm.cs with empty functions.
This obviously causes compiler error until I manually remove them in MyForm.cs.

How can I prevent these functions from being regenerated?

I saw a question about [Placing these kind of files under the main.cs in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485851/winform-partial-classes), could this be the solution that would tell visual-studio to find the existing functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method in [WinForm partial classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485851/winform-partial-classes) I placed MyForm.LeftPanel.cs below MyForm.cs.

So far this seem to have solved the problem.